# MultipartResolver and AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm having trouble using `CommonsMultipartResolver` bean in conjunction with an initializer that extends `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`.

I have successfully used CommonsMultipartResolver in a previous project, but the initializer implements `WebApplicationInitializer`.

Intuitively, I did this in the initializer extending `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`.

```
@Override
  protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[]{
        MultipartUploadConfig.class
    };
  }

  @Override
  protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[]{
        WebMvcConfig.class

    };
  }
```

I thought it would have the same effect as with this code in `WebApplicationInitializer` (This is the working config).

```
@Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherServlet = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherServlet.register(WebMvcConfig.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherServlet));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(MultipartUploadConfig.class);

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
    }
```

Using `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`, I get the following error:

```
Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided
```

So, anyone knows how to make multipartResolver bean work with `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`?

Other relevant information:

WebMvcConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = ...)
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
  ...

  @Override
  public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
  }

}
```

MultipartUploadConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class MultipartUploadConfig {

  @Bean
  public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(8192);
    multipartResolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
    return multipartResolver;
  }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
[http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception
 org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:78)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:76)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter.doFilterInternal(MultipartFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2669)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParts(Request.java:2636)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParts(RequestFacade.java:1083)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:85)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: This works fine for me on Spring 4.x. Post more of your config. Write up an MCVE.

Comment: Okay, You're correct, this works in Spring 4.x. I tried making an MCVE and apparently, its not the Initializer that's messing up the multipartResolver. It appears to be the security filter. I guess the question is now how to use multipartResolver with Spring Securit 3.x. I'll work on an MCVE and update the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it. The `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` and `WebApplicationInitializer` versions indeed do correspond to one another. No problem there. The problem was that in the project using `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`, there was also Spring Security and that messed things up.

When using Spring Security, the Bean name of the multipart resolver should be `@Bean(name = "filterMultipartResolver")`. Of course, this means that `MultipartFilter` should be setup in the `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` like this.

```
@Override
  protected void beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext) {
    insertFilters(servletContext, new MultipartFilter());
  }
```

Comment: Hi, Richard. I am getting org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No multipart config for servlet exception. Used same settings like yours, I am using Jetty server. Can please share some more points on how you used in controller.

Comment: I wish I could up vote it 100 times :) @Ramki  take bean name as given in the answer, filterMultipartResolver, it will work hopefully.

Comment: The solution worked for me. However, CORS is not working on the upload URL.